# Removing part of url with htaccess (and redirect?)

Tags: .htaccess

I need to change url with .htaccess from

```
http://mywebsite.com/p/info/team/contact/
```

to

```
http://mywebsite.com/info/team/contact/
```

and from

```
http://mywebsite.com/article.php?id=ID
```

to

```
http://mywebsite.com/article-ID/
```

I have only that code:

```
RewriteRule ^article-([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /article.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^article-(.*)/ /article.php?id=$1
```

My .htaccess (containing webhosting content):

```
RewriteEngine On

# subdomeny (s nebo bez www na zacatku)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subdom/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdom/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)\.([^\.]*)\.([^\.]*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdom/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) subdom/%2/$1 [DPI]

# aliasy - spravne presmerovani pri chybejicim /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^domains/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]

# subdomeny - spravne presmerovani pri chybejicim /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^subdom/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [R]

#errory - presmerovani
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404-not-found/

RewriteRule ^p/(.*)$ /$1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteRule ^article-(.+?)/?$ /article.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: `RewriteRule ^article-([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ /article.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^article-(.*)/ /article.php?id=$1`

That's all what I have.

Comment: Is this rewrite or redirect? Or both?

Answer (score 0):

You need these 2 rules in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^p/(.*)$ /$1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteRule ^article-(.+?)/?$ /article.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

**Full .htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^p/(.*)$ /$1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteRule ^article-(.+?)/?$ /article.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# subdomeny (s nebo bez www na zacatku)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^subdom/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdom/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)\.([^\.]*)\.([^\.]*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdom/%2 -d
RewriteRule (.*) subdom/%2/$1 [DPI]

# aliasy - spravne presmerovani pri chybejicim /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^domains/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R]

# subdomeny - spravne presmerovani pri chybejicim /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^subdom/[^/]+/(.+[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R]

#errory - presmerovani
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404-not-found/
```

Comment: Q0. What is your URL that didn't work? Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess?

Comment: 0. http://playblock.net/p/informace/pravidla/
1. only one
2. added to question
3. location of .htaccess is /www/.htaccess (document root)

Comment: But your URL is not even starting from `/p/` ? So this rule won't even fire.

Comment: You need to use a different browser may be. With these rules when I entered: `http://localhost/p/informace/pravidla/` it became: `http://localhost/informace/pravidla/` so rules are in good shape. Problem is in your local code/config.